# Константы, общие для многих модулей

Tags: c++, c

У меня есть модуль, управляющий АРУ. 2 файла - *agc.c* и *agc.h*. Период АРУ задан в *agc.c*: `const uint16_t AgcPeriod = 10;`

Теперь он понадобился другим модулям, но если я перенесу его в *agc.h*, то мой сборщик (Keil 4.53) выдаст ошибку: "имя определено во многих объектных файлах".

Единственный выход - заменить переменную макросом: `#define AgcPeriod 10`.

Но при этом исчезает контроль типов и эта переменная автоматом становится `int`, а не `uint16_t`.

Можно также в каждом модуле, которому нужна эта константа, писать 
`extern const AgcPeriod;` и ссылаться на нее как на внешнюю, но тогда я не могу в этом же модуле определять константы, опирающиеся на эту. То есть я не могу написать: `const uint16_t myConst = AgcPeriod + 1;`.

Существует ли решение этой проблемы?

Comment: Язык C. В C++ для этого есть свое решение?

Comment: Давайте обе метки оставим, мне интересно как это решается и в C и в C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В C++ достаточно написать `const uint16_t AgcPeriod = 10;` глобальный const объект в C++ имеет internal linkage. В C такого правила не существует, поэтому компилятору нужно указать свои намерения явно:

```
static const uint16_t AgcPeriod = 10;
```

Этот вариант будет работать и в C++, но он избыточен т.к. `static` подразумевается в C++ по умолчанию.

Comment: `const uint16_t AgcPeriod = 10; глобальный const объект в C++ имеет internal linkage` -- но если где-то перед ним написать строчку `extern const uint16_t AgcPeriod;`, то он становится глобальным (в таблице символов "тип"? изменится с `r` на `R`).

Comment: @avp, ну да, linkage станет external. Но это уже из другой оперы. Ни разу не видел константы с external linkage. По крайней мере в C++ коде

Comment: А я их вообще всегда `#define`-ами пишу (как-то проще все получается (да вы загляните в /usr/include/...))

Answer (score 4):

1. Для указания типа используйте приведение прямо в макросе или расширения числовых литералов:

   ```
   #define INT_CONST         ((int)10)
   #define FLOAT_CONST       ((float)3.14159)
   #define UNSIGNED_CONST    (10u)
   #define LONG_DOUBLE_CONST (3.14159l)
   ```

   Однако, здесь мой VC2012 работает странно, например для такого кода:

   ```
   const long long int CONST1 = 10;
   #define CONST2 ((long long int)10)
   #define CONST3 (10ll)

   void foo()
   {
       float f1 = CONST1;  // выводится предупреждение
       float f2 = CONST2;  // предупреждение не выводится
       float f3 = CONST3;  // предупреждение не выводится
   }
   ```

   Почему так — для меня загадка, возможно, другие компиляторы будут вести себя     более последовательно, поэтому и привел это решение.
2. И железный вариант использовать функции:

   ```
   static uint16_t AGC_PERIOD() {return 10;}
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Извиняюсь за объем ответа (из-за примеров), но понятно (надеюсь, что понятно) короче написать не сумел.

Обычно проблем возникать не должно, хотя использование внешних переменных (констант) — это достаточно тонкий момент, особенно для смеси модулей (раздельная компиляция) из C и С++.

**Пример для Linux g++ и gcc**

Заголовочный файл, который включаем во все модули:

```
#ifndef _EX_H
#define _EX_H
#include <stdint.h>

extern int64_t v1;
extern int8_t v2;
extern const uint16_t cv3;

#ifndef USEPLUSPLUS
// with -DUSEPLUSPLUS g++ makes C++ function names (like _Z6ex_priPKc) in .o
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#endif

  void ex_pri (const char *title);
  void ex1 (void);
  void ex2 (void);

#ifndef USEPLUSPLUS
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define COMP "g++"
#else
#define COMP "gcc"
#endif

#endif
```

`#ifdef`-ы вокруг прототипов нужны только если планируете использовать смесь из модулей, откомпилированных gcc (C) и g++ (C++).

Теперь 4 файла с нашими функциями:

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ more ex.c ex1.c ex2.c ex_pri.c | cat
::::::::::::::
ex.c
::::::::::::::
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ex.h"

int
main ()
{
  printf("main (%s): cv3 = %hu\n", COMP, cv3);
  ex_pri("start");
  v1 = v2 = 10;
  ex_pri("mid");
  ex1();
  ex2();
  ex_pri("finish");

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
::::::::::::::
ex1.c
::::::::::::::
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ex.h"

void 
ex1 ()
{
  printf("ex1 (%s): change v1 = %lld to cv3 / 2 + 1\n", COMP, v1);
  v1 = cv3 / 2 + 1;
}
::::::::::::::
ex2.c
::::::::::::::
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ex.h"

void 
ex2 ()
{
  printf("ex2 (%s): change v2 = %d to cv3 / 2 + 1\n", COMP, v2);
  v2 = cv3 / 2 + 1;
}
::::::::::::::
ex_pri.c
::::::::::::::
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <iostream>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ex.h"

int64_t v1 = 777666555444333222LL;
int8_t v2 = -127;
const uint16_t cv3 = 0xABCD;


void
ex_pri (const char *title)
{
  printf ("%s\nex_pri (%s): v1 = %lld v2 = %d cv3 = 0x%04x\n",
      title ? title : "", COMP, v1, v2, cv3);
#ifdef __cplusplus
  std::cout << "++++\n";
#endif
}
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

в которых по всякому манипулируем внешними переменными. Кстати, обратите внимание: определение переменной (константы) должно быть однократным. Здесь все определения в файле `ex_pri.c`.

И можно поиграться с разными вариантами компиляции

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ gcc -c ex1.c ex2.c ex_pri.c
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ ex.c ex1.o ex2.o ex_pri.o
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out 
main (g++): cv3 = 43981
start
ex_pri (gcc): v1 = 777666555444333222 v2 = -127 cv3 = 0xabcd
mid
ex_pri (gcc): v1 = 10 v2 = 10 cv3 = 0xabcd
ex1 (gcc): change v1 = 10 to cv3 / 2 + 1
ex2 (gcc): change v2 = 10 to cv3 / 2 + 1
finish
ex_pri (gcc): v1 = 21991 v2 = -25 cv3 = 0xabcd
End
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ nm ex_pri.o
00000000 R cv3
00000000 T ex_pri
         U printf
00000000 D v1
00000008 D v2
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ -c ex1.c ex2.c ex_pri.c
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ ex.c ex1.o ex2.o ex_pri.o
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out 
main (g++): cv3 = 43981
start
ex_pri (g++): v1 = 777666555444333222 v2 = -127 cv3 = 0xabcd
++++
mid
ex_pri (g++): v1 = 10 v2 = 10 cv3 = 0xabcd
++++
ex1 (g++): change v1 = 10 to cv3 / 2 + 1
ex2 (g++): change v2 = 10 to cv3 / 2 + 1
finish
ex_pri (g++): v1 = 21991 v2 = -25 cv3 = 0xabcd
++++
End
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ -c ex1.c ex2.c ex_pri.c -DUSEPLUSPLUS
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ nm ex_pri.o
00000000 R cv3
         U __cxa_atexit
         U __dso_handle
000000b1 t _GLOBAL__sub_I_v1
         U printf
00000000 D v1
00000008 D v2
00000072 t _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
00000000 T _Z6ex_priPKc
         U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
         U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
         U _ZSt4cout
00000000 b _ZStL8__ioinit
         U _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ ex.c ex1.o ex2.o ex_pri.o
/tmp/ccp5Fn5P.o: In function `main':
ex.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `ex_pri'
ex.c:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `ex_pri'
ex.c:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `ex1'
ex.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `ex2'
ex.c:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `ex_pri'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Видите, здесь компилятор (g++) ожидает имена функций в «сишном» формате, а мы ведь уже сделали `.o` с C++ именами функций (это определяется `extern "C" ...` в заголовочном файле). Поэтому перевызовем:

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ ex.c ex1.o ex2.o ex_pri.o -DUSEPLUSPLUS
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out 
main (g++): cv3 = 43981
start
ex_pri (g++): v1 = 777666555444333222 v2 = -127 cv3 = 0xabcd
++++
mid
ex_pri (g++): v1 = 10 v2 = 10 cv3 = 0xabcd
++++
ex1 (g++): change v1 = 10 to cv3 / 2 + 1
ex2 (g++): change v2 = 10 to cv3 / 2 + 1
finish
ex_pri (g++): v1 = 21991 v2 = -25 cv3 = 0xabcd
++++
End
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

Ну, и так далее.

Comment: #if defined(__cplusplus) && ! defined(USEPLUSPLUS)